# Android: Showing array list item to listView

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android , I have an `arraylist` but I want to show its value in a `ListView` ,but I am unable to do that.I have searched many methods like `ArrayAdapter` and `BaseAdapter`s etc.but not helpful.Can anyone help me here is my code...

```
prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude,longitude, timezone);

ArrayList prayerNames = prayers.getTimeNames();
for (int i = 0; i < prayerTimes.size(); i++) 
{               
    txtPrayerTimes.append("\n" + prayerNames.get(i) + " - "
        + prayerTimes.get(i));              
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? and post your code what you have tried till now

Comment: can u add logcat and post your code

Answer (score 2):

First, Please post your full code. anyway you can use the following code to show tha data in ListView

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("item1");
    list.add("item2");
    list.add("item3");
    list.add("item4");
    list.add("item5");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list items are strings just use `ArrayAdapter` like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simepl_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

If your list items are some objects then extend `toString` method for that class and use array adapter for strings again.

**EDIT**

Or you can extend `ArrayAdapter` for the class you want and implement method `getView`.

Comment: See the updated answer, and also try to Google a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps of [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) Here you will get description of all points..

Answer (score 0):

A simple tutorial for [list view with array list](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php) you should follow.